Driving with different sized tires
My truck tire is flat and I noticed a 1/2 crack in my rim.
I have a spare but it is a different size 275 65 r18 is it safe to drive home about a 3 hour drive and then park it?
My truck tires are 275 55 r20

Both wheels are 32" / 800mm down to the liberal tyre-making accuracy.
Don't worry.
Otherwise:
4x4: depends on 4x4 system, but on newer cars generally avoid.
4x2: put the different wheel on the non-powered axle.
